# Read a set of lines from a file using BufferedReader

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, java-io

I have one large CSV file of around 1.6 GB and I am trying to read that file and create JSON array of these lines and send it to other consumables processes.

I have the following code

```
while(consumeover){
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader
                                ("/my/path/largefile"),65536)) {
         for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
         String[] dataRow = line.split("\\|");
         //create json array
         //add each dataRow element to array  
         }
    }
   }
```

Now what is happening is above code reads entire file and creates json array which throws "Out of Memory" error. I want to read set of lines say 1000 lines every time I create json array. How do I set my last read position to i+1000? As file is very large, Java is throwing out of memory because of data arrays getting created.

Comment: There is no [tag:nio] here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to output each line as you get it (not save it in an array and then send/write it), or every 1000 lines as you get them.  This way you only read the file in one go. The less line you hold in memory, the less memory you use.

Note: the only way to read to from line N is to read N lines and ignore them.  This would become increasingly expensive as the file get larger.

Say you have a method which translates a line of CSV into JSon.

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
    PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outfile))) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
        String json = process(line);
        bw.println(json);
    }
}
```

This will only need enough memory for one line of CSV and one line of JSON, no matter how big the file is.

Comment: Hi @Peter thanks a lot for the answer. Will it scale? As I have very large files 1.6G is the smallest one. Will RandomAccessfile would be helpful? I am new to File IO so not sure what is the best?

Comment: Why wouldn't it scale?  You could have a 1 TB file.  I don't see how NIO would help.

Comment: I am not able to understand your approach will you please help me with simple code.

Comment: @user449355 I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. What is outFile in sample code?

Comment: @user449355 the file you are writing the json to.  Where is the JSon you are creating going to go? i.e. why are you creating it?